# Apply value on ionic-rating

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am am using this plugin [ionic2-rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-rating)for user to rate other user which is saved on the db. I have the value from the db I would like to display it on read only rating input but is not working for me have tried using `value` , `checked` and rating which is used on the `ngModel` but sting not working for me.

```
<rating readOnly="true" max="5" checked="{{myValue}}" ></rating>
```

Comment: `<rating [(ngModel)]="myValue" readOnly="true"></rating>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` like this

### HTML

```
<rating [(ngModel)]="rate" readOnly="true" max="5"></rating>
```

### TS

```
export class HomePage {
    rate = 2;
}
```